# Between Subjects Likert Analysis -- Treat as Ordinal or Continuous for Stats Test?

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert

I have 4 groups in a between subjects design answering likert scale questions. I am wondering how to analyse the data. There are 20 questions for each user in each group of 30 (so 120 people all together, with 120*20 responses).

I see two options

1. I could simply lump all questions in each group together and have a big distribution of 20*30 datapoints, each a number between 1-5. In this case, I'd have to use Mann-Whiteny U.
2. I could average each persons 20 questions to reduce each user to one floating point number, and have 30 datapoints for each group. Here I could use a T-Test or ANOVA etc

The thing is, I have no idea which is correct, I have seen people do both, and I have never gotten a straight answer which is correct. I know people use both methods, religiously, but is there actually a correct answer here?

Thank you if you can give your opinion!

Comment: In order to add the items, you must already be assuming they're interval scaled. How else can you assert that "1" + "4"  (e.g. by the first subject on the first two items) is the same value as "2" + "3" (another subject on the same two items)?

Comment: See also: [www.researchgate.net/post/Between_Subjects_Likert_Analysis--Treat_as_Ordinal_or_Continuous_for_Stats_Test](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Between_Subjects_Likert_Analysis--Treat_as_Ordinal_or_Continuous_for_Stats_Test)

Comment: Just to distinguish: you have 20 Likert *items*. A Likert *scale* is made up of Likert items, typically by summing the integer-assigned Likert item responses. Is it the case that the 20 questions are intended to make up a single scale? Parametric techniques (t-test, ANOVA, or more generally, linear models) do just fine typically with Likert scale data. Actually, they often do fine with *item*-level data as well.

Comment: So, would a correct thing to do be this?

Take the median of each person, then you have one datapoint for each person. Then, you can run a non-parametric test of t-test if the sample is big enough?

Then you can look a box plots, ranges, interquartile ranges etc?

Comment: There are indeed several positions on this with pros and cons. The first thing I'd be interested here is however what your aim is. What do you want to know and why do you need a test? A key problem here is scale construction, i.e., what exactly you want to measure, how this is related to the questions, and what has been done to validate the Likert scale that could be used here. By the way Mann-Whitney U compares two groups not four, and the "big distribution" in your option 1 will surely violate the independence assumption, so this is not the way to go here anyway.